# How to set connectTimeout in case of slow internet and if I don't know the size of file to download

Tags: java, android, settimeout, httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

```
private fun downloadAPKStream() : InputStream? {

        val url = URL(this.url)

        val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.requestMethod = "GET"
        connection.connect()            connection.connectTimeout = 5000

        fileSize = connection.contentLength

        val inputStream = connection.inputStream
        return inputStream
    }
```

I'm using this method to download apk file. But here if internet is slow then due to timeout of 5000 ms, download gets stuck in between without get completed. And if I comment this line or I don't provide any **connection.connectTimeout then it runs fine but sometimes get stuck in infinite time loop. What should I do to make it download files of any size and with slow internet as well.

Comment: Setting the connect timeout after the connect is a complete waste of time. The connect timeout affects the connect operation. It has nothing to do with the download operation or the file size. If you had set a *read* timeout it would affect the time for each individual read, but again it would have nothing to do with the total file size. 5 seconds is pretty short for a read timeout. Too much confusion here.

Comment: And it doesn't 'get stuck in an infinite loop'. It gets stuck in a blocking read, *because* you have *not* set a read timeout. So do that. But more than 5 seconds please.

Answer (score 3):

You got `timeout` meaning wrong. It is not a max. allowed time of given (network in this case) operation, but max. allowed time of **inactivity** after which operation is considered stalled and fail. So you should set the timeout to some **sane** value, that would make sense in real life. As value is in [milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29), the `5000` is not the one because it's just 5 seconds - any small network hiccup and your connection will get axed. Set it to something higher, like 30 secs or 1 minute or more.

Also note that this is **connection** timeout only. This means you should be able to establish protocol connection to remote server during that time, but this got nothing to data transfer itself. Data transfer oa process that comes next, once connection is established. For data transfer timeout (which definitely should be set higher) you need to use [setReadTimeout()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)).

Finally, you must set connection timeout **prior** calling `connect()` otherwise it makes no sense as it is already too late - this is what you got in your code now.

PS: use [Download Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) instead.

Comment: But it goes into stalled state showing download percentage forever without increasing a bit. And I can't use DownloadManager. I must use HttpUrlConnection for this task. Please help me with that.

Comment: You can't use it why?